# Python Set Parent to an Instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Is there a way to just set a parent object to a particular instance?  I have a utility that initializes a complex object for me and i'd like to have it init some objects for mocking.  Example:

```
class ComplexObject:
   def __init__(arg1, arg2, arg3):
       #do some stuff
       return

class ComplexObject_Mock(ComplexObject):
    def __init__():
        complexObject = ComplexObjectFactory.NewComplexObject()
        return super() = complexObject
```

Now I know the above doesn't work, because of the last line.  Usually I create the instance of the parent class by using `super().__init(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, but instead of that i'd like to just set the instance to something initialized by the factory.

Comment: Even if you could that, that would be some really bad code design in my opinion

Comment: Its for mocking, not production code.  I agree its wonky, but could result in faster mocking.  I maybe misunderstanding the role of super().__init__ as well.

Comment: You could do this in the `__new__` method.  I'm a little confused about why you would do this, and what you expect the final result to be.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, I just don't want to manually design a bunch of mocks where I have to constantly specify super().__init__ args, especially when I have a factory that already handles these complexities for me.

Comment: @RafaelC, my mock requires I extend the object returned by the factory.  Thus I inherit from it, and we end up in the current sitch

Comment: @RafaelC, not sure I would gain anything by that.  I'd start with a complete ComplexObject in my ComplexObject_Mock init method, but i'd still have to handle all the intricacies of the ComplexObject within the ComplexObject_Mock.

Comment: Python doesn't have parent class subobjects in the first place; `super().__init__(...)` doesn't create an instance of the parent class.

Comment: @Jamie alright, won't brainstorm anymore in comments, but i'd take abarnet's suggestion !

Comment: @RafaelC, thanks, I think i'm just looking at the super().__init__ wrong.  The answer here maybe just to make ComplexObject implement the factory internally and be able to call that.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are multiple problems with this line:

```
return super() = complexObject
```

- You can't do an assignment (or any other statement) inside a `return`, only an expression.
- You can't do an assignment to the result of a function call, only to a nameable target—a variable, an attribute of an object, an index in a list, etc.
- If you could do an assignment to the result of a function call, that wouldn't do anything useful. You'd just be rebinding some invisible temporary name to a different value.
- Even if you could, `super()` returns a special magic proxy object, so forcing it to return some other object that doesn't know how to act like a `super` would just break everything.
- Finally, what `super()` returns is a proxy to `self`. If you somehow made it into a proxy into a completely unrelated object, then every method you called on `super()` would end up accessing and mutating the attributes of that completely unrelated object, which would have no effect on `self`.

Also, `__init__` is a normal method, that requires a `self` or it can't be called.

Meanwhile, if you're trying to change the way an object is created, not just the way it's initialized, you have to use `__new__`, not `__init__`.

Finally, the whole point of mocking is that you *don't* have to create a `ComplexObject`; you're creating something that *acts* like one without *being* one, so the whole thing doesn't make much sense in the first place.

This is kind of a wild guess, but I think what you *really* want here is a proxy object that *owns* a `ComplexObject`, and also fakes being one, delegating some calls and handling others on its own. In other words:

```
class ComplexObject_Mock(ComplexObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self.complexObject = ComplexObjectFactory.NewComplexObject()
    def method_to_delegate(self, arg):
        # instead of return super().method_to_delegate(arg)
        return self.complexObject.method_to_delegate(arg)
    def method_to_steal(self, arg):
        # don't call self.complexObject.method_to_steal
        # just as you wouldn't have called super().method_to_steal
    def method_to_hook(self, arg):
        arg = self._preprocess(arg)
        # instead of result = super().method_to_hook(arg)
        result = self.complexObject.method_to_hook(arg)
        return self._postprocess(result)
```

Comment: This is actually, exactly what i'm avoiding.  I don't want to write any of that code, proxy, or wrapper anything in my ComplexObject_Mock, just extend the native object where I have too.  The world real world application of this for me is to create Mock objects with as little code as possible.  The problem is the parent object has quite a few rules governing its creation and I don't want to have to deal with those either, thus my factory.

Comment: @JamieMarshall You can generate the methods dynamically, or even just create them on the fly with `__getattr__`. I can't give a concrete example without an example of what you're trying to do. If you don't want to edit your question to contain a [mcve], you can search for `Python proxy __getattr__` and I'm sure you'll find good examples.